# Tags by new users?

Tags: discussion

Imagine the following:
You are a new user with 1 rep. You want to ask a question about a manga/anime, that has no tag yet (in my example: Chaos;Head, tag would be [chaos-head](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chaos-head)). How should such a user tag the question? He can't use the tag for the manga/anime, because it doesn't exist yet/he can't create it, he can't ask at meta or in the chat, because he hasn't enough rep yet and he can't use a generic tag like [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime), because they're blocked. What should the new user do?

Should new users have the possibility to create new tags for new series? I think that's a bad idea, but it's the only one I could think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bad idea, simply because a new user doesn't know how the system works. He doesn't know what is the accepted format for tags in Stack Exchange in general.

Even a user who's active on another site (And thus gets a 100 point bonus), doesn't know what the accepted tag scheme on *this specific* site is.

If a user wants a question tagged with a specific anime which doesn't exist, the expected behavior is:

- Find a tag which closely matches what he wants
- Either wait for a retag by a high-rep user.
- Even better, flag the question for retagging by a moderator.

I understand the system is problematic, but allowing new users to arbitrarily add tags induces more problems than it would solve.

Comment: `Find a tag which closely matches what he wants` Yeah. However, what would be the best tag for the posted example-question? Which tag should the user use?

Comment: @looper: Be it [tag:plot-explanation] or [tag:characters], there are plenty tags to use.

Answer (score 3):

The rep limit is to avoid that any drive-by user can create a tag (even non-sensical or offensive wordings).

It's a protection for us. If a new user wants a retag, they can simply ask so in a comment. Any regular user will add the tag.